# How to find every 10 digit number starting from 4?

Tags: combinations

```
How many 10 digit numbers are there starting from number 4
```

There are 1 000 000 000 possible combinations of 10 digit numbers. I want to find out how many of them actually start with number 4

Rules :
Find all possible combination of every 10 digit number which starts from number 4.

I am good at programming but weak at mathematics, Now when such challenges come across it becomes difficult to think about some mathematical solution. Any reference helpful would be nice.
Thanks

Comment: Do you mean with first digit $4$?

Comment: By "starting from number 4", do you mean the first digit is 4?  How many other digits are there?  How many possible values are there for each?

Comment: Yes 10 digit number that starts with 4

Comment: Finding "every," as in the title of the question, means listing them. But the body of the question asks for a count. But then in the "rules" line, you say "find" again.

Comment: Are you using each digit $0$ through $9$ just once or will any 10 digit number starting with 4 work, like $4555411111$?

Comment: Alternate hint: every integer from $\ldots$ to $\ldots$.

Comment: The number of 10 digit numbers is $9\times 10^9$, not $10^{10}$.

Comment: If you can count all the non-negative integers below $1000000000$, then adding $4000000000$ to each of those will give you all the $10$-digit numbers starting with $4$,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your question is "how many 10digit numbers are there with the first digit being a $4$", note that all such numbers are of the form:

$$\underbrace{\underline{4}\underline{~}\underline{~}\underline{~}\underline{~}\underline{~}\underline{~}\underline{~}\underline{~}\underline{~}}_{10~\text{spaces}}$$

You can answer this directly by noting that it will be every number from $400\cdots0$ to $499\cdots 9$, or you can answer this via [multiplication principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_product).

To see this via multiplication principle, set up the sequence of choices:

- Choose the first digit.  (*How many choices do we have for the first digit? we required that it be a 4, so there is only one choice*)
- Choose the second digit.  (*For this, the second digit could be any of the list $0,1,2,\dots,9$ for a total of 10 possible choices*)
- Choose the third digit.  (*similarly there are 10 choices*)
- $\vdots$
- Choose the tenth digit.  (*similarly there are 10 choices*)

According to the multiplication principle, the total number of ways of completing the task is the product of the number of choices at each step.  I.e. there are $1\cdot \underbrace{10\cdot 10\cdots 10}_{9~\text{copies}} = 1\cdot 10^9$ possible 10 digit numbers which begin with a 4.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:  how many two digit numbers are there that start with $4$? how many three digit numbers? For three digit numbers, you have to choose two digits after the $4$.  If you don't see the pattern, you could write a short program to count how many four and five digit numbers there are.

Comment: Hey I got that pattern and it's much more efficient than writing a program to count all! , Thanks :)

Comment: @AnonDev:  This is called the [rule of product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_product)  If you have $a$ choices for one thing and $b$ choices for a second, you have $ab$ choices for the pair.  You have ten choices per digit.

Answer (score 0):

Note that you can stick all ten-digit numbers into nine buckets:

1. $1,000,000,000$ to $1,999,999,999$
2. $2,000,000,000$ to $2,999,999,999$
3. $3,000,000,000$ to $3,999,999,999$
4. $4,000,000,000$ to $4,999,999,999$
5. $5,000,000,000$ to $5,999,999,999$
6. $6,000,000,000$ to $6,999,999,999$
7. $7,000,000,000$ to $7,999,999,999$
8. $8,000,000,000$ to $8,999,999,999$
9. $9,000,000,000$ to $9,999,999,999$

Every one of these buckets contains $1,000,000,000$ numbers.

(Don't believe me? Let's do a small example and look at the numbers between $0$ and $9$: we have $0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9$. Count them, that's $10$ of them. Do the same for $10$ through $19$: we get $10,11,12,13, \ldots ,19$ -- it's always $10$.)

All numbers starting with a $4$ are in the $4$th bucket, which contains $1,000,000,000$ numbers. So there are $1,000,000,000$ ten-digit numbers that start with a $4$.